# Add shadow to custom UISlider knob image?

Tags: ios, uikit, uislider

I need to place a custom knob image with shadow for UISlider. So far i have a image of 38x38, of which there is a region which defines the shadow of knob.

[image: Knob Image@2x]

now while using this image, when i slide the knob to extreme ends the actual knob is not able to cover the end points, hence end points are visible under transparent region of the knob image

[image: knob at the extreme end]

This is the code I am using to customize the UISlider

```
UIImage *slideBtImg = [UIImage imageNamed:SliderKnobImg];  
[self.ratingSlider setThumbImage:slideBtImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];  
[self.ratingSlider setThumbImage:slideBtImg forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

How can I implement a custom knob with shadow beneath it, properly covering the end points??

Answer (score 1):

Look inside `UISlider.h`, there are methods that let you customize the slider knob and track as needed. (iOS 2.0 and above)

```
// lets a subclass lay out the track and thumb as needed
- (CGRect)minimumValueImageRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds;
- (CGRect)maximumValueImageRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds;
- (CGRect)trackRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds;
- (CGRect)thumbRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds trackRect:(CGRect)rect value:(float)value;
```

Here is my own example. It requires some math work. I get a valueRatio of the current slider position (from 0 to 1) and adjust it to make my shadowed custom knob to nicely be at center. Hope that helps ;)

```
- (CGRect)thumbRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds trackRect:(CGRect)rect value:(float)value {
    float valueRatio = ( value - self.minimumValue ) / valueRange;
    return CGRectMake(valueRatio * (bounds.size.width - 26) + 3, 7, 20, 20);
}
```

Comment: what is `valueRange`?

Answer (score -1):

You can add some transparent space to your image `SliderKnobImg`. Keep the image's width smaller than your slider's, then use `[slideBtImg resizableImageWithCapInsets:...]` as your slider's  **thumbImage**.